# Python SimpleHttpServer, how to return files without extensions with plain/text mime type?

Tags: python, httpserver, socketserver

I coded following simple http server in python, I have some files without an extension and want to serve them with "text/plain" mime type. How can I achieve it?

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 80

class Handler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    pass

Handler.extensions_map['.shtml'] = 'text/html'

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [the module's source code](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py#L201) this should work:

```
Handler.extensions_map[''] = 'text/plain'
```